# I want to do 3 filled circles in a row without interfering with anything else

Tags: row, geometry

I would like to get some help with this. I've tried so many different ways and no one works. I want this in only HTML and CSS.

```css
.circles {
        background-color: white;
        height: 70px;
        width: 70px;
        border-radius: 40px;
        position:relative;
        margin:10px auto;
        display:inline-block;
}

.row {
        
        height: 100px;
        width: 700px;
        margin: 10px;
        text-align:center;
        position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="circles"></div>
            <div class="circles"></div>
            <div class="circles"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Put the code you have tried that does not produce expected result.

Comment: I added it now, the thing with this is that its not centered in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example via jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/tezocucufi/edit?html,css,output

There are a couple different ways to get it to "not interfere" with other elements... but depends on what your situation.

Circle code:

```
border-radius: 50%;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```

Alignment could be with floats, or:

```
display: inline-block;
```

and position'ing both the element and the parent container to position it on the page.

Reference: https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-circles.php

Comment: Thank you, how do I get this always in the middle of the page?